# Styled Component Not Inheriting Extended Styles

Tags: reactjs, jsx, styled-components, tsx

I'm unable to figure out how extend my styles from my Styled components based on how the docs say they should work. I sat with a coworker and they also had no success. My component is this:

```
const PageBodyElement = styled.p<{ size?: 'small' | 'medium' | undefined }>`
  color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.text};
  font-family: ${(props) => props.theme.fonts.default.family};
  font-size: ${(props) => (props.size === 'small' ? '1.4rem' : '2.1rem')};
`

interface PageBodyProps {
  children: ReactNode
  size?: 'small' | 'medium' | undefined
}

export function PageBody(props: PageBodyProps) {
  return <PageBodyElement size={props.size}>{props.children}</PageBodyElement>
}
```

I/we want to be able to do something like this:

```
// outside of render
const ErrorTextPageBody = styled(PageBody)`
  color: red;
`
//inside render
<ErrorTextPageBody>Hello World</ErrorTextPageBody>
```

Where we can tweak one CSS property, in this case text color, without needing a new component or a new parameter. I get no errors and it renders just fine, however, the font color (or any and all styles) dont change. To me this seems exactly like the how-to guide on the Styled Components website says to do it but I've had no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit 1:

i think i get what you mean.

Maybe you can pass `className` to your `PageBodyElement`.

here's sentence from the [official docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#:%7E:text=Styling%20any%20component-,The,prop%20to%20a%20DOM%20element.,-NOTE):

```
The styled method works perfectly on all of your own or any third-party component, 
as long as they attach the passed className prop to a DOM element.
```

So, with that logic, you should pass the `className` first like this:

```
interface PageBodyProps {
  children: ReactNode
  className: any // don't know the type
  size?: 'small' | 'medium' | undefined
}

export function PageBody(props: PageBodyProps) {
  return <PageBodyElement size={props.size} className={props.className}>{props.children}</PageBodyElement>
}
```

And maybe you can extends it after that. I haven't tried it, but you can test my speculation

Comment: Wouldn't this lose the functionality of the component? For example, I don't think I could pass `size` to this anymore since this isnt extending or modifying the actual component just exporting an element. PageBody is the simplest example but other components, like inputs with far more options, we'd want to tweak styles without needing to copy paste into new components.

Comment: We have a custom `Link` component for example that actually is a wrapper to React Router DOM `Link`. We extend those styles like this: "const LinkElement = styled(ReactRouterDOMLink)..." and that works great. Later I could use like ` <StyledLink to={href} target={target}>` and note the `to` and `target` are passed along. Id like to be able to do something like that

Comment: I've edited my answer, maybe you can check it out